# Search in SQLite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

### Problem Description

I have SQLite database, in which I keep some information, one of the columns keep information about company name, it can be formatted like this **"This is a new company"** or **"Google Inc"** or **"New company of USA"** or "USA base company". Now I want to write a query which will search through the database and give all items which words starts with search word.

For example if I search USA word

it must search database and find all words in the sentence which start with USA

Comment: **it must search database and find all words in the sentence which start with USA** ????

Comment: no all sentence which words stars with "USA" @user370305

Comment: Look at http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php

Comment: Let's explain how the % wildcard works in the SQL LIKE condition. We are going to try to find all of the suppliers whose name begins with 'Hew'.

SELECT * FROM suppliers
WHERE supplier_name like 'Hew%';

Comment: @user370305 must I use SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE supplier_name like 'Hew%';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the input of the user and then just do a query like :

```
SELECT * FROM Company
WHERE company_name like 'USA%';
```

You will have just to replace USA by the user's input.

**EDIT :**

If you want to find all compagnies where the `compagny_name` contains USA just do :

```
SELECT * FROM Company
    WHERE company_name like '%USA%';
```

Comment: Is this same as String.contains("USA") ? @ZouZou

Comment: Same as myString.startsWith("USA"); @ViToBrothers

Comment: So it will find this to "New company of USA" or only "USA base company".

Comment: It will find records where company_name starts with "USA" so only "USA base company" in this case

Comment: and how I can do to find all words in the sentence start with USA

Comment: I'm really confused, could you give a concrete example of input and output ?

Comment: for example I have 
Google Inc. 
Best of Google
Best Search Boot is Google

I search Google in this case all three must be find.

Comment: @ViToBrothers Check my updated answer. Here if you have "USA compagny" / "Best USA compagny" / "Google is an USA compagny" , the three will be find

Comment: I want something like that

Comment: Then you have to use '%USA%' :)

Comment: Be careful because like is case sensitive then if the user enter 'uSa' this won't work. But it's your job to format the user's input. Uses wildcard is the good approach for what you want to implement. Is it ok ?

Answer (score 2):

It would be typical sql syntax (for all rows where information column values starts with USA):

```
select * from table where information like 'USA%'
```